# Extending svcutil.exe and wsdl.exe with custom methods

Tags: wsdl.exe, svcutil.exe

I really need to add some of my own convenience methods into the auto-generated proxy files that are output by wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe.  What I am doing is adding another type of ***Operation***Async method for each service method.  I would like to be able to invoke a tool from a command line like this:

**superwsdl.exe [wsdl command-line arguments here]**

**supersvcutil.exe [svcutil command-line arguments here]**

And have the outputted file include my extra methods.  Does anyone know a way of doing this?  If it has to be another format of command line, that is OK too.

Comment: How'd you do? Did you get your two programs written?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about svcutil.exe, but wsdl.exe generates C# `partial` classes.

You can make another `partial` class with the same name and put the extra methods there.

Answer (score -3):

It should be your consol application written in for eg. C#, which will take some arguments and  do something like this:

...

```
Process svcUtil = new Process();
svcUtil.StartInfo.FileName   = "svcutil.exe";
svcUtil.StartInfo.Arguments = "... some arguments here: args[0], args[1], ...";
svcUtil.Start();
```

...

Vedran